# Phpmailer Script Not Executed

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, phpmailer

I am writing this code where there is 2 user type : **Normal User** & **Admin User**.

Normal User Submit Data To Admin User, Both Admin (More Then 1 Admins In database) & Normal User Should Receive Email Regarding The Submission Of Data.

The submission and retrieving of the data **is working fine**. But in the Email Part, I reuse the code from my registration part that works for the submission code, Result is, **It does not read the $mail**.

Both of my registration and submission files **are in the same folder**. (Path should be working fine).

The logic also seems fine. Maybe i forget or miss something ? Could use a help to check my code.

```
...//
if ($conn->query($sqlDeleteSelected) === TRUE)
{ 
   require_once  "../assets/inc/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";   
   $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try 
{
   $sqleMail = "SELECT * FROM users_details WHERE users_Admin_University_Name = '$basket_UniCourse_UniName_1'";
   $resultSqleMail = $conn->query($sqleMail);
   while($dataResultSqlMail=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultSqleMail))
   { 
     $mail->AddAddress($dataResultSqlMail['users_Email']);
   }
   $mail->From = "myemail@gmail.com";
   $mail->FromName = "MyName";
   $mail->isHTML(true);
   $mail->Subject = 'Application Registered';
   $mail->Body = 'Congratulations!';
   $mail->Send();                                        
     if($mail->Send())
        {
           // echo "Message has been sent successfully";
              ?>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                       alert("sucesss");
                  </script>
              <?php
        }
    else
       {
             ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                     alert($mail->ErrorInfo);
                </script>
             <?php
       }
}
   catch (phpmailerException $e)
     {
            echo $e->errorMessage();
     }
  catch (Exception $e)
     {
         echo $e->getMessage();
     }
}
//..
```

Thank You So Much.

Comment: What do you mean by _“Result is, It does not read the $mail”_?

Comment: I don’t understand the question either, but I can see you’re running a very old version of PHPMailer, and you’re calling `send()` twice, so you’ll get duplicate messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you 100% correctly but I assume that the java script "success" or the alert is not executed? This is because your `if` condition is not used properly. Actually you are trying to send the email twice:

```
 $mail->Send();                                        
     if($mail->Send())
        {...
```

A better way to see if the email was send successfuly is using a try&catch:

```
try {
    $mail->send();
    // print success message
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // print error message
}
```